# Can props be forged in React?

Tags: reactjs, security, forge

Pardon me if this is a ridiculous question. But can props be forged in React? In other words can someone navigating your website find a way to deliberately change the values of the props that are being passed from component to component in a manipulative way to bypass the natural flow of your website?

Comment: In a very quick non-answer, yes, it can. React runs purely on the browser under direct control of the user, and he can change **everything** from the debug options of devtolls, data and even alter the code directly if he really wants. That's why a key security concept is "never trust the client" and perform every critical access control server side.

Answer (score 1):

No, in React, props (short for properties) are values passed from a parent component to a child component. They are immutable and cannot be changed or forged within the child component. The child component receives props and uses them to render its output based on the provided data.

If you need to modify data or manage state within a component, you would typically use state in a class component or the useState hook in a functional component. Props, on the other hand, are intended for one-way communication from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant change the props in react. But yes you can provide callbacks, or make use of context APIs, redux, localstorage, etc to let your parent component know the updated value!!